# PHP partial string match

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm new to PHP.

I'm trying to search through an array of data, and match any item that contains a partial string

EX: if user inputs "oh" the search will find any item containing "oh", so the item could be John.

I have this so far, doesn't match anything

```
if(isset($_POST['firstName'])){
    for($i = 0 ; $i<count($studentInfo);$i++){
        if(strpos($firstName,$studentInfo[$i][2]))
```

of course there is other code to do something once the item is found. I've seen a lot of substr methods, and STRPOS functions, I just can't figure out how to make it work with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Looking closer at your question, it seems as though you are searching for matches within the values of an array. There's something similar to preg_match() for this called [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

```
$arrMatchingValues = preg_grep("/^findme/", $array);
```

---

Take a look at [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Using some sample code from that page:

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

`$subject` is what you want to search.
`$pattern` is the regex pattern that you'd like to match against.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a [regular expression.](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php) In your specific case, you should loop through the array, and for each item, use preg_match (as detailed in the linked article). Any matched items should be added to another array, or you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I'm trying to make this preg_match work with my code, would this go inside the second if loop?

Comment: As per PHP [http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php]: Tip
Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.